# Сортировка по концу строки php

Tags: php, сортировка

Привет. Есть поле в которое вводится данные вида:

```
23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2
23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3
23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15
```

и так далее. Количество пробелом между тремя частями строки РАЗНОЕ.

Эти данные сохраняются в файл на сервере, затем выводятся в упорядоченной форме (сортированной). Обычная сортировка упорядочивает строки по первым символом, а мне требуется вывести отсортированные по третьей части (`XXX-1.2.2/12-3`). Может кто подсказать, как?

Comment: Дубликат вопроса. Не могу найти, к сожалению. Скорее всего вы и задавали. Что вам мешает разделить строки по пробелам, забрать последнюю часть и использовать ее в качестве ключа для нового массива?

Comment: @DaemonHK, зачем его искать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/754440/186083 Но там нет ответа. Оформите ответ с вашего комментария.

Comment: Прошу прощения за повтор. Увидел.

Answer (score 3):

Христоматийно: [uasort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php)

```
$array = array(
    "23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2",
    "23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3",
    "23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15"
);

function cmp($a, $b) {

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    $a_cmp = substr($a, strrpos($a, 'XXX'));
    $b_cmp = substr($b, strrpos($b, 'XXX'));

    return ($a_cmp < $b_cmp) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');

echo "<pre>" , print_r($array) , "</pre>";

/*
output:
Array
(
    [1] => 23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3
    [0] => 23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2
    [2] => 23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15
)
1
*/
```

**UPD** Как это работает:

Функция **uasort** принимает два параметра. Первый - это массив, элементы которого необходимо сортировать. Второй - пользовательская функция, которая циклично (магия) принимает в качестве аргументов по два элемента массива `function cmp($a, $b) {`, и сравнивает их `return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;`. В данном конкретном случае мы перед сравнением выделяем последнюю часть строк `XXX-1.3.2/14-2 и т.д.` элементов с помощью функции **strpos**

```
$a_cmp = substr($a, strrpos($a, 'XXX'));
$b_cmp = substr($b, strrpos($b, 'XXX'));
```

и сравниваем уже только их.

```
return ($a_cmp < $b_cmp) ? -1 : 1;
// если левое меньше правого, вернуть первым левое ( -1 )
// иначе вернуть первое левое вторым ( 1 )
```

Кроме **uasort()** есть функция **usort()**. Делает то же самое с тем отличием, что не сохраняет ключи массива.

```
uasort output:
Array
(
    [1] => 23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3
    [0] => 23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2
    [2] => 23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15
)

usort output:
Array
(
    [0] => 23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3
    [1] => 23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2
    [2] => 23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15
)
```

Comment: Хех, жаль я плохо такие штуки знаю((

Comment: я не знаю, как это работает (пока), но это работает!Спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

Целостность данных ваших я не знаю, но самое простое решение примерно такое:

```
<?php
$input=array(
    "23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2",
    "23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3",
    "23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15"
);
//get new array
$output=array();
foreach($input as $string){
    $strArray=explode(" ",$string);
    $key=$strArray[count($strArray)-1];
    $output[$key]=$string;
}
ksort($output);
//check new array
var_dump($output);
```

P.S. Может кто-то знает более компактное/быстрое/правильное решение?

Answer (score 0):

Обьеденю два ответа

```
array = array(
  "23123123 ыаыаыава XXX-1.3.2/14-2",
  "23123121231233 ыаыафывфыава XXX-1.2.2/12-3",
  "23112323123 ыаыаыававфыв XXX-2.1.2/12-15"
);

function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a == $b)
    return 0;

  $a_cmp = explode(" ", $a);
  $a_cmp = $a_cmp[2];
  $b_cmp = explode(" ", $b);
  $b_cmp = $b_cmp[2];

  if ($a_cmp == $b_cmp)
    return 0;
  return ($a_cmp < $b_cmp) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp');

echo "<pre>" , print_r($array) , "</pre>";
```